# Mockito verify() method was invalid when class has @SpringBootTest annotation

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm doing unit test, and from debuging, the commonService.executeCommon("A", "B") is indeed executed, but tests failed with an error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
commonService.executeCommon(
    <any>,
    <any>
);
```

And everything's fine if I remove SpringBootTest annotation, why did this happen? Is there a way the tests can be passed without removing SpringBootTest annotation?
here's code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private CommonService commonService;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;


    /**
     * Method for general test case setup
     */
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldExecuteCommon() {
      
        myService.doService();
        verify(commonService).executeCommon(any(), any());

    }

}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {

    private final CommonService commonService;


    void doService() {
      
       commonService.executeCommon("A", "B");

    }

}
```

Comment: Can not reproduce using `MyService` provided, how did you inject commonService into it?

Comment: Actually used an annotation @RequiredArgsConstructor, I've edited the code. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: Not sure why your service has no @Service annotation. I did try out that it will work if you remove `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);`

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will works by removing

1. `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`
2. `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);`

We should not use `@RunWith` as it is for `junit4` class, `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` is the way for `junit5`, and should be the proper way for this case. `@SpringBootTest` should be for integration test.

It is not documented why `@SpringBootTest` process mockito annotation automatically.
But by inspecting the source, [`spring.factories`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories#L13) in spring-boot-test contains
`org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener`,
which do the job when we add `@SpringbootTest`.

Comment: So it may be because there is some kind of conflicts when using @SpringbootTest and MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) at the same time?

Comment: yes, as `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks` is called twice